# Texture-painted images turn black when used?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I was experimenting with texture painting and noticed something really, really annoying.

I spent 15-30 minutes painting, saved, then used the map as a texture. Note that I saved immediately after painting and before setting the object texture.

As soon as I did, it turned black. I couldn't make it go back, so I quit, making sure to not to save the messed up image. When I opened the save, the map was still messed up.

Does it automatically save changes to the UV even when the blend it's self isn't saved?

Comment: Did you save the *texture*?

Comment: no,since it didn't appear right. I did set the mapping and everything. checking the image viewer confirms that it was overwritten somehow. I don't know how it's saving the bad image though :/

Comment: But you said you "saved" it.

Comment: @ZCoder Blender doesn't save texture data with the blend file by default, you must pack the image or save it to your hard drive. It will save the image datablock, just not the pixel data (resulting in an apparently black image)

Comment: @Leon I saved it BEFORE it turned black. I made sure not to save it any time when it was black.

Comment: @ZCoder Sorry, I'm still not sure I understand. Did you save the texture (`F3`) or the entire .blend (`Ctrl+S`)?

Comment: @gandalf3 I saved the entire blend(ctrl+s)
I assumed that meant it actually saved all the data associated with the project. does it only save certain types of information?

Comment: @ZCoder Yes. If you pack the texture image (*Image Editor > Header > Image > Pack Image*), that will save it, but you have to pack it again every time you want to save it.

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/texture-paint-texture-i-painted-is-gone

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14050/599. Voted to close as duplicate, even though this question was first. OP said in comments that they didn't save the image, so most likely the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem ... you just open a new tab and open the uv/image editor , in your 3d view go into edit mode for the object you want ( which is black ) , and then in the uv/image editor , click the texture panel and select the texture you want .[image]