# Why did the texture I painted in texture paint mode disappear?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I was following a [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_WZvTAcaUc) on how to use the Texture Paint feature on blender so I could paint on a terrain I am modeling.
I was successful to paint the whole terrain with beautiful, exuberant vegetation, and crystalline water running through the valley.

So I saved my file, and I went to sleep.
But now I've reopened the file and everything seems like I left it yesterday, except that I can see no texture in the terrain...
The weird thing is that the textures i used are still there...
I don't understand, I barely understand the interface, please help.
I'm not even sure if the texture is there or if it was never "saved" or something...

[image]

I am now going through the second part of the tutorial for possible answers but I (and hopefully many more) will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5691/599

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14050/599

Comment: If you wan't to save them automatically, try using this script: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15782/3127

Comment: Lost work issue dated 2015 [has been closed unresolved](https://developer.blender.org/T45636). Such non finished design was standard at the time TRS 80 was used, but we are in the 21th century now and checking a dirty file before exiting is BAU... The worst is saving the project don't tell you you didn't save all the files.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to save the image texture to an image file <kbd>F3</kbd> (*Menu: Image / Save As Image*) otherwise all changes are lost. Blender indicates an unsaved texture in the *UV-Editor* with an asterisk at the *Image Menu Item*.

[image]

Another option would be to [pack the image](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Types/Image) into the .blend file.

[image]

Comment: :'( i feel so sad and stupid at the same time, thank you!

Comment: nice thx, here another related link https://blenderartists.org/t/texture-paint-how-to-save-it/650723

Comment: Wow this is unintuitive, why doesn't it do what every other program does "You have an unsaved texture... save it?"

Answer (score 4):

Did you save the texture? Blender will not automatically save the texure for you as the texture is an external file.

If the image has not been saved you will see a start indicating so in the UV view.

[image]

Don't forget to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> to save the image.

Comment: Does this mean i forever lost the one i made yesterday?

Comment: yes, they are gone forever. You will need to start over again.