# Why blender is not saving used Images

Tags: image, blend-files

I was wondering if someone could explain me why blender is not saving images when I save the project?

I know that this is treated as external data and it's not really big deal to save it manually but consider case where you don't know the program well.
Normally like in all other programs, when you save a project you expect that it's going to look exact the same when you load it again but in blender you could have a Big surprise especially when you spent few hours on it. 
And even if you are experienced user you could forget to save it and little mistake can lead to waste much of your time.

I'm aware of this topic [Auto save images along with .blend](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13407/auto-save-images-along-with-blend)

But I'm asking why is Blender behaving in such way. It don't seem hard to program such thing so it must be a matter of choice which i can't understand but even a simple warning will be very helpfull.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a feature request

Comment: I remember not too long ago blender used to quit without prompting you to save. This is another one of those loose ends that needs tidying up

Comment: @cegaton I don't think the OP is requesting the feature (it's been requested enough already, there's even a working patch), so much as asking *why* this was ever designed this way.

Comment: @gandalf3 yes, that is what i meant.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reduce the size of the .blend file. Blender to a Maximum extent save only relative references. If you want to Shift your project to some other machine.You have to pack all the project files.

To save all the images to the .blend file Checkout File-> External data section

Comment: Ok, but who said that it has to be saved inside blend file? Edit as external file - save as external file.

Comment: by default only references are stored in blend file. If you want your images in the blend file. Then you have to pack your image