# How to save texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

Ok, I have fully colored/textured a pretty decently sized hatchet I made in blender a few times now and each time I saved and closed my blender. When I reopen the blender file it is completely unpainted.... Being very frustrated what am I doing wrong? I've tried saving the image of the texture but it keeps telling me "invalid path:" and I can't see the rest of the error message. I think my problem is that I'm saving the blend but not the texture mapping thing. (sorry don't know the correct terminology for everything)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UV map / model turned black on saving - how to recover?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14050/uv-map-model-turned-black-on-saving-how-to-recover) and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/texture-paint-texture-i-painted-is-gone/7683#7683

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13407/auto-save-images-along-with-blend

Answer (score 1):

Try this: press spacebar and then type "Pack." Select "Pack all into .blend". See if that works. That will copy all the source files blender uses (in this instance: texture images) into the .blend file. I don't entirely know if it will work, but I hope it will.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39271/69959