# Packing Texture Files In a Single Blend File

Tags: blend-files, linked-data

How do I pack texture files in a **single** blend file in blender cycles. I am using Sheep it Render Farm to render one of my animations and I need to make sure the texture files in this **single** blend file are packed so it renders with them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Blender-> File -> External Data -> Automatically pack into .blend (click to activate) and save the file as usual. The images will be packed as part of the blend file.

Comment: Does it work if you have linked objects from other files?

Comment: I'm trying to pack my blend file to take it to Sheep It, but the problem is that when I hit pack all into .blend, it says unable to pack file, source path not found. But the textures are showing up and rendering fine?

Comment: This did not work for me since I tried to pack a movie. As of Blender 2.92, this is not supported yet. Manually packing the project will return "No new files have been packed" and packing the image manually will return "Packing movies, image sequences or tiled images not supported".

Answer (score 2):

For render textures in Sheepit I do the following: File, external data, unpack all into Files, create directory if needed, and then.. .copy the textures manually to the Textures folder blender creates... next, zip all into a file and upload the zip to SheepIt. And it does it !

Hope it helps