# Why is my texture showing pink in render view when the image path is correct and cycles is the render engine?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

I am having the exact same issue as discussed in this thread:
 [Why does this texture appear fine in material view but appears pink in rendered view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67954/why-does-this-texture-appear-fine-in-material-view-but-appears-pink-in-rendered)

[image: Tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xU_pi1UxISs]

The image file is not missing - I have used "find missing files", as well as assigning and unwrapping again. The image shows up in the 3D view but is only visible as pink in the render view. I have exported the file from PS as a TIFF with alpha. Is this a bug or am I and [Sarsha W](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/31518/sarsha-w) doing something wrong?

I'm running Blender 2.78a on a PC.

*BTW, I've been going step by step from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xU_pi1UxISs) tutorial, and the alpha channel texture is the only one with this problem*

Comment: Did you try to save the file and reopen it?

Comment: Yes, and it's still pink. Does it have anything to do with how the surface was originally modelled? It was created by making a duplicate from a selection of the cup's ribs (see the tutorial from [11:35](https://youtu.be/xU_pi1UxISs?t=11m35s)

Comment: No, the pink color means that blender doesnt have access to the image file. Try to reopen it.

Comment: I've been opening and reopening since yesterday. Following exact instructions from [here](https://youtu.be/xU_pi1UxISs?t=42m39s) in the tutorial. Once I have opened the image under image texture, it is still pink. File path is correct,  no missing files when I use File > External Data > Report Missing Files. When I unwrap, make a new texture, save and reopen it's still the same problem - texture is visible in the 3D view but not render view. Sarsha W has been having the exact same problem, posted 3x about it and still hasn't resolved. I'm using Blender 2.78a on a PC, if that helps.

Comment: Can you post both your .blend & image file? Actually before you do, can you try packing the image file, that may solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, that's what did it! Blender-> File -> External Data -> Automatically pack into .blend

Comment: I'd say this is a bug which was eventually resolved by packing.

Comment: Feels like a bug.

Comment: I have a feeling that Blender was trying to modify the color space encoding or something like that, but couldn't  because it is trapped in a tiff file. Once packed blender is free to do whatever it wants to with the data, while leaving the file untouched. It was a gut feeling from my perspective as I really don't understand all the different image encodings and their limitations, but it seemed worthy of a try. What I do know is some file types hold more color data than others. Glad it worked out.

Comment: I did a little research on the tiff format, and confirmed my suspicionson a little better. I stumbled across this [site](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/faq.html), as it seemed to sum up my vague memory of what a tiff file could do/store. Both color space info, along with other encoded info can be stuck in there, so there may be a high likelihood that this problem would be repeatable if someone using a different color space saved their image into a .tif without converting to sRGB. Blender is going to try and convert it, but I doubt it would try and change the original file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rick Riggs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/21718/rick-riggs) suggestion to pack the image file:

Blender-> File -> External Data -> Automatically pack into .blend

worked like a charm. Once I checked that, the texture was applied to the surface. 
[image: .blend after packing image data]

For help packing images: [Packing Texture Files In a Single Blend File](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39257/packing-texture-files-in-a-single-blend-file)