# Manuel Bastioni LAB characters are rendered pink/purple on different machines

Tags: manuel-bastioni-lab

I have made some .blend files on my Windows machine at work and now when I try to render them with my mac at home they render pink or purple (Not good at colors!).

From [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73165/40350) I tried `Blender-> File -> External Data -> Automatically pack into .blend` but I get the error:

> Report: Error
>   Unable to pack file, source path /Program Files/ Blender Foundation/ Blender/2.79/scripts/addons/manuelbastionilab/data/textures/human_female_diffuse.png not found

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://www.versluis.com/2017/04/how-to-render-manuel-bastioni-lab-characters-without-purple-skin-in-blender/) I found that the missing textures should be assigned again. So selected

`Blender-> File -> External Data -> Find missing files`

and then went to the folder

`/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.79/scripts/addons/manuelbastionilab/data/textures/`

The issue was solved. Now to avoid this happening again you select select the `Blender-> File -> External Data -> Pack all into .blend` so the textures will be integrated into the .bled file and don't have to be loaded from original texture folder every time.