# Sprites turn pink when moved to another computer

Tags: texturing

I am having an issue with transferring files that contain sprites. On one computer they have an image and when I move the file to a different computer they come out pink? Can someone please help me?

Comment: You need to re-link the images in Blender. You could also "Pack" the images in the original .blend before you move it to another computer. A quick search of the Blender Stack Exchange for "pink" will yield more information for you.

Comment: images used on blender scenes (as textures, backgrounds, etc) are not saved within the blend file by default. You would need to pack the image to make the file self contained. Go to file>External Data> pack all into file and then save the file again. Note that the size of the file will grow. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39257/packing-texture-files-in-a-single-blend-file/39271#39271