# Why isn't "Pack all into .blend" / "Automatically Pack into .blend" packing materials or images?

Tags: packed-data

Blender 2.92.0.

I have three files: `source.blend`, `destination.blend`, and `test_image.png`.

`source.blend` consists of a single cube with a single material on it. The material has an Image Texture node which reads `test_image.png` from the local directory. This all works as expected.

`destination.blend` consists of a single cube. After *File ⭢ Link...* and selecting the material in `source.blend`, the material is applied properly to the cube. This all works as expected.

Now, if within `destination.blend`, I select *File ⭢ External Data ⭢ Pack All into .blend*, I get the message "No new files have been packed." If I move `destination.blend` out of the directory, so that it can no longer reference `source.blend`, the material is no longer available.

The documentation suggests that only some kinds of assets can be packed into a `.blend`, but I would imagine materials should be on that list, no? Even if I don't link the material, but instead just create a new material with the Image Texture set to the PNG image, pack everything, and move `destination.blend` into an isolated directory, the image isn't packed either.

What am I missing?

Similar Questions:
[Packing Texture Files In a Single Blend File](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39257/packing-texture-files-in-a-single-blend-file) does not answer the question. The accepted answer simply says to use *File ⭢ External Data ⭢ Pack All into .blend*, which as I described doesn't work. In the comments under the accepted answer, the asker points out that as of 2.92, "Packing movies, image sequences or tiled images not supported". But the image in question is not a movie, image sequence or a tiled image, and besides that, I've also demonstrated that materials are not being packed as well.

I've attached the files I created. You can create any valid PNG image as `test_image.png` within the same directory.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing two separate concepts.

- **Packing**  is for *external media files*. So `.png` image textures, `.txt` texts and `.py` scripts, `.ttf` fonts, etc. can be packed. Packing embeds those entire *files* as binary blobs in the current `.blend` file.
- **Linking** is for *specific ID data blocks from another `.blend` file*. So Objects, Meshes, Armatures, Actions, Materials, Curves, Scenes, Cameras, Worlds, etc. can be linked. These linked data blocks can't be "packed" because there isn't anything *to* pack— They're read from part of the library `.blend` file, so they don't correspond to any single, whole external file that can be embedded in your current `.blend` file.

You probably want to use "Make Local", which will basically copy the specific data that's been linked from the library `.blend` file into the current `.blend` file. You can also click on the little number or chain icon next to the ID data block selector field, which will make a copy of it in your file, although you might then have to switch every user of that data block to the new copy separately.

Comment: So _Pack All External Data_ only refers to external media on the filesystem? That's... Okay. Well anyway. What is the proper way to have all of the assets of linked files self-contained in the file referencing them?

Comment: @wherezyurheadat I think **"Make Local" —> "All", followed by "Pack All"** should do it. (Note: Originally had error in answer, said "Make Single User" instead— Might also work, but will create unnecessary duplicate data.) The order matters because you want the linked images to be in the file for packing. Could also "Append" instead of "Link" from the start, depending on workflow. Set your Outliner to "Blender File" to see what data is currently linked from library files at the bottom, or "Data API" to check for the value of "Packed File(s)" for all images.

Comment: @wherezyurheadat This will get linked `.blend`/"DNA" data, images and fonts, but not video clips IIRC (understandably, IMO). Run this code in your Python console panel to get a list of any media files that haven't been packed: `[d for a in dir(bpy.data) for t in [getattr(bpy.data, a, [])] if hasattr(t, '__iter__') for d in t if not getattr(d, 'packed_file', True)]`

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

Materials don't pack.  Or, maybe, they're always packed.  You could think about it either way.

Images pack.  But I'd suspect that any issues you have are related to the fact that you're *linking* data from a different file.  No matter what you do, linked data is going to use the info from the file from which you linked it.  There's nothing to pack, because the image texture isn't being referenced by the file you're in; it's being referenced by the file you're *linking*.

If you want to pack stuff, edit stuff, unlink the objects (+ mats.)  You cam use the "make single user" menu for that, 'u' in 3D viewport object mode for me, which I think of as "unlink."  If you want to see the file size change, of the linked file, pack/unpack stuff in the source of the linked data.

Comment: ...They killed the "U" hotkey around 2.8, I think. I have to search in the `F3` menu for "Make Single User" nowadays.

Comment: @WillChen Pre-2.8 interface FTW :)  Only thing I miss is 3d viewport f2 renaming....

Comment: 2.49 had a `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`P` BI render preview popup that only rendered part of the screen... Quite nice compared to the current rendered view mode, with limited processing power. I still have muscle memory for `F1` and `F2` to save/open.... I think I actually go through the "File" menu these days; I'll use the normal shortcuts elsewhere, but they just don't feel right in Blender.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know that was a thing. I used the old `F2` "Save as" so much that it seemed kinda sacred lol.