# Qubicle to blender for import to Unity - don't know if texture is actually applied?

Tags: texturing, unity

Ok, I am fairly new to 3D modeling but Ive picked up qubicle for some 3D voxel game characters to import into my Unity game. It's great, and Ive made a few models that I have colored inside qubicle. I read up everywhere on importing qubicle to blender (because I need to apply an outside texture i.e. a pattern not just color, still don't know how to do this) and found that .obj are the way to go.

So I exported to obj file and got the obj, .mtl, and a png with my "textures" (just colors). I then imported this file to blender and in normal object mode I get the model with no colors:

[image]

However when I go to texture paint mode I see the texture colors applied as they should be:

[image]

I am now going to embark on figuring out how to texture map and apply some additional patterns to my model like this tile example (notice the little grass texture):

[image]

however before doing this I need to know - are my color textures being applied? Meaning if I bringing this blend file into unity like this and dragging my png file onto the model -[image]

if I add some external texture via uv mapping in blender will this texture be preserved?
How can I apply the textures I add in blender? Have never done anything like this.

Comment: Unity reads diffuse color you have in the materials in Blrender but textures you need to set up separately, so make a new Unity material and assign texture to it. Make the texturing using UV so the mapping carriers over to Unity.

Answer (score 1):

The 3DView has several different [shading modes](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/display/shading.html) ranging from bounding box to render preview. By default, in solid shading the objects are drawn in a plain colour and any textures are not visible, while they aren't displayed in the 3DView they are used when rendering and exporting. When you change to texture painting, the textures are displayed as that is the data you are working with.

Something that can catch you out is that you need to save the image files after painting as they are not saved when you save the blend file. The answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13407/935) has a script that will save the images when you save the blend file.

If you search for "[blender texture painting](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender%20texture%20painting)" you can find many tutorials to get you started.