# Can you save UV images automatically? (Along with when you save a file)?

Tags: texturing

So a lot of times I lost all my texture paint work, sometimes I forgot to save it, sometimes it mysteriously turns to a previous 'save'. Either way, it would be much easier if the textures would save automatically along with a 'overall' file saving... its kinda hard to keep track when you have multiple materials...

Maybe there's an addon?

Comment: There is a script - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13407/auto-save-images-along-with-blend. See also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14050/uv-map-model-turned-black-on-saving-how-to-recover

Comment: Ah thanks man. So you just copy the text, save the file as .py and just Install as an addon?

Comment: Yes as it's already covered everything there. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon. Also basics of creating addon - https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_71_release/info_tutorial_addon.html.