# warning message when the images has not been saved

Tags: texture-painting

I'm doing texture painting and using a new texture. Sometime after painting i forget to save that image and when i quit there's no warning at all. Is there any setting in Blender to prevent this ?

Comment: I don't think so, I never understood why though...

Comment: There isn't default way to do this (not sure about recent 2.8 builds) however there was written script quite a bit ago https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13407/auto-save-images-along-with-blend which doesn't appear to work in new versions

Answer (score 1):

There is not a warning per se, but the image name in the Image Editor will have an asterisk next to it indicating it has changes to it - also, on my system, I do get a warning when closing a file that there are changes not saved. There is an option to pack all images into the file, and that works for some people - but also best practice is to save the image to disk first, and then make use of the save all dirty images operator.

Comment: That's the big problem . The warning is only for modifying the project file but not for unsaved image. Try this out :  1.  Edit the project and do the painting, close Blender, it will give you a warning, Now save the project but DO NOT save the image. Now close the blender and you will not see any warning. 2. Try to re-open a project file with texture paint, don't do anything else, just apply some paint stroke. Now , close Blender. Surprise.... it will close immediately and silently. Btw, I know that asterix sign , but that just not enough to save my life :-)