# How to totally save a self-contained Blender object to ensure no data is lost?

Tags: workflow, blend-files, linked-data

From reading questions [like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/why-did-the-texture-i-painted-in-texture-paint-mode-disappear?rq=1), it seems that saving a .blend file does not actually save everything in it.

What settings do I need to apply so that Blender always totally saves the file every time I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, so that no data will be lost?

I want to be sure that any changes to textures, UV maps, etc are preserved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's any easy way to save everything, but the closest to what you want is to activate the automatic packing of external data.
This doesn't, however, save everything. For instance, it doesn't save the render result.

To activate this, go to *File>External Data>Automatically Pack into .blend*.

[image]

Video files or image sequences will not be packed.

Painted textures have to be saved as external files before they can be packed (else they will disappear).

Physics cache can be saved to disk (with different commands), but will be saved  on a folder where the original blend file is stored, but will not be packed as part of the blend file either.

For more specifics please see: https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/data_blocks.html?highlight=pack#data-block-types

Comment: Render result is also not saved.