# How can I "pack" an image sequence?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I'm using an online renderfarm to get something rendered out, and one of the textures in my scene is using an image sequence. I can't pack this in the traditional way, so I thought I could put the frames in a separate folder inside the folder with the .blend, and zip the main folder. When I go to upload it, it says that the frames are missing, and if I open the .blend in the ZIP file, the image texture is purple. I tried to re-open the frames by hitting the "open" button in the image editor, but I can't get see/get into the .zip! Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is that when I open up my file in blender, the reference picture is gone](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44225/why-is-that-when-i-open-up-my-file-in-blender-the-reference-picture-is-gone)

Comment: @10Replies That question is simply asking how to pack an image. Mine is an image sequence, and won't pack like that.

Comment: If you zip only the folder with sequence it won't see it. Zip whole folder with the project (a way to that is to put sequence into subfolder and point Blender there) and then once it's unzipped the sequence will be there. Note, it won't see images if unzipping only the file.

Comment: @MrZak I didn't just zip the sequence, I have the sequence in a subfolder within the zip. I can't point Blender to it because I can't see or open the .zip file when I go to add the images.

Comment: I meant to point Blender to sequence before zipping the folder with both .blend and sequence. After unzipping that back Blender recognizes the sequence because it didn't change location relatively to the file. Check if paths are set to relative in File > External Data.

Comment: Why not packing your image sequence in the blend file and save your .blend with "compress" option checked?

Answer (score -1):

I just have this problem today, and I found the fix for it. I use concierge render and it has the option to upload a folder and you can also connect your dropbox to their website. All the Image sequence textures were fixed.