# How can i apply a PNG logo on my material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, uv, image, uv-image-editor

I have a project with a material I want to add to my sphere. I want to add this logo onto the sphere. I have tried various ways of uv mapping but I keep messing up :/ [image]

This is my current material setup:

[image]

And here is what I would like to have:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have now changed my setup like the answer stated, but my material still changes with the PNG, so it becomes black although my material is red

MY SETUP (NEW):[image]

Something (probably a small setting) is stil wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: problem is i got this material preset and idk how to recreate it with the tutorial u posted. im really a newbie im sry

Comment: 1-Use a color mix node and use the alpha channel of the image as factor to mix theimage's RGB information with the base color used in the diffuse shader: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybxkL.jpg.

Comment: 2-When uploading blend files always pack the images, otherwise the image will not be part of the file (See [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44225/why-is-that-when-i-open-up-my-file-in-blender-the-reference-picture-is-gone/44228#44228)) 3. Please do not use file sharing sites that try to charge money to download files. Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ instead. 4- Here's a link to your fixed file on the site mentioned earlier: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4105" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4105/).

Comment: thanks alot ! ill keep it in mind i didnt know what website to use i just took the first one of google

Answer (score 0):

you need a "Transparent BSDF node (see image). PM if you get stuck[image]

Comment: HI , thanks for ur answer . idk how to send u a PM . but i copied ur node setup and added it to my. it actually worked but my material which is red isnt applied. the sphere is just black.  do u know how to fix this?

screenshot:   https://prnt.sc/h7ukrc

Comment: Can you post the .blend file?

Comment: i did update the thread , blend file is added