# Lost image used for modeling. Now I get pink

Tags: modeling

I was modeling a character head from an image background and have lost my image since I moved the blender file to another location . what do I do to make it come back instead of the pink colored area where my image should be ?
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are all the textures in my file pink?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)

Comment: Read also: [Why is it that when I open my file the reference picture is gone?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44225/why-is-that-when-i-open-up-my-file-in-blender-the-reference-picture-is-gone/44228#44228)