# Saving textures and materials

Tags: uv

I recently heard that it is a good idea to save the texture image not only in the textures panel...but also in a other panel as well, I think it was the uv mapping panel? Or image veiwer? And that if you didn't and closed it down then you may loose some of your work. If this sounds familiar to anyone, I was wondering why you hade to save it in essentially 2 different windows?  Does Maya or 3dm have these kind of ideosyncresies also in anyone's experiance?

Comment: I haven't heard of saving it in the textures panel, just creating there.  *Then* go to the UV image editor, click on the Image menu, and save it outside your .blend, but I haven't explored this fully/used it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is about misunderstanding. Maybe someone doesnt know what your talking about or maybe you don't understand how to ask the question right? In either case......
If you save image to HDD, it will be saved. ..done. There is no reason why Blender should be  deleting them.

**But:**
If you bake, paint, texture, or edit an image in Blender, then you must save them  before you close the project. **Blender will don't save images when you save .blend file.**

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14050/uv-map-model-turned-black-on-saving-how-to-recover and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/why-did-the-texture-i-painted-in-texture-paint-mode-disappear and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43046/how-to-totally-save-a-self-contained-blender-object-to-ensure-no-data-is-lost/43047#43047

Comment: Ok, so if I am making a texture by importing a png to be made into a UV map....I save it in the UV / image window under tab....image>save. And also under main toolbar  file>save.   And if I save as a .blend file......it will not save the file images...?    Is this why the tab source..."pack an image as an embedded data into .blend file"  exists in the texture properties editor..? If so, when would I want to or not want to use the "pack image as embedded data into the .blend" file option?

Comment: If you import texture to .blend, you do not need to save it. Textures are saved on your HDD. If you use one in material, Blender save only path to texture. "Pack external data" is something else. This feature save all data directly to .blend. This is useful only if you need move .blend, send .blend to someone else or to render farm. Does not give sense always pack all textures to .blend and have many duplicates of the same textures on your HDD. Duplicates in sense: one original texture on HDD and copies of the same textures packed in your .blend files.