# How to resume editing

Tags: video-sequence-editor

How do you resume your editing if its saved as a .blend file, I tried editing a video sequence I saved it with .blend, now when I open it with blender its showing a blank output with strips, How do I resume my editing ? [image]

Comment: Are the video files in the same place on the hard drive?

Comment: @cegaton yes it is

Answer (score -2):

Found.. Had to do file->external data->Automatically pack into blend,
and then save as .blend unfortunately lost the edited sequence

Comment: Video files will not be packed into the blend file. Editing is done by referencing external files and rendering into new video files. There is no way to make the video files be contained as part of the blend file.

Comment: please read:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43046/how-to-totally-save-a-self-contained-blender-object-to-ensure-no-data-is-lost/43047#43047

Comment: read: https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/data_blocks.html?highlight=pack#data-block-types

Comment: @cegaton so is there a way around this to contain everything in blend file ?

Comment: NO there is no way to pack video files in a blend file. Please read the links.

Comment: I do not know of any video editing app that saves the video files as part of the project file. It makes no sense.

Comment: what about openshot that can save the project ?

Comment: @santhoshkumar I'm pretty sure openshot project files just save a reference to the existing video files, like how blender does in .blend files. *Maybe* it copies them to a "work space" directory, or something similar. I've seen an option like that somewhere IIRC (kdenlive?). If you need the videos and .blend all in one file, would putting the videos in the same directory as the blend, then tarring (or zipping) the whole lot suffice?