# Some images are painted on. These changes will be lost. Continue?

Tags: texture-painting

I get this message when attempting to pack all textures.
My actual question is: How to easily locate those "unsaved" textures?

I did this before with a copy of this file and there were no problems. The difference this time around is that I packed some textures individually. Then I went to the File menu and chose External Data/Pack all into .blend.

Thanks guys,

DPC

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/why-did-the-texture-i-painted-in-texture-paint-mode-disappear

Comment: Thanks for replying cegaton :)
I am quite aware of what you say, BUT "...My actual question is: How to easily locate those "unsaved" textures?"

Comment: If you have all these images saved *as files* intially (via `F3`) and there's unsaved paint since then, you can use UV/Image Editor > Image > Save All Images.

Comment: Also in Outliner there's property for whether image is unsaved - open Datablocks, Blendfile Data > Images > imagename > Dirty. If it's checked then image has unsaved changes.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't save the painted textures as images they will be irretrievably lost. **Blender does not save painted images on the blend file by default**. They need to be saved as images first (F3). Only then you can pack them into the file and save.

To know if an image has been saved see the bottom bar on the UV/Image editor window: Unsaved images (Images that have been altered, or painted over) will show a star (*) right next to **Image** on the menu.

Once they've been saved (<kbd>F3</kbd>)the star will diappear and they can be packed properly into the blend file.

[image]