# Painted Texture Not Rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

In Cycles, I have painted some textures onto my UV map like below:

[image]

While in Texture Mode I can see the paint applied.

[image]

But when I go to render mode, they do not show.

[image]

My nodes are setup as follows:

[image]

Comment: Did you saved painted texture before living Texture Paint mode?

Comment: @LukeD Oh goodness. That was it. If you move this to an answer I will accept it. Thank you so much!

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/why-did-the-texture-i-painted-in-texture-paint-mode-disappear and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49622/some-images-are-painted-on-these-changes-will-be-lost-continue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, always **Save All Images** in **Slots tab** (**Texture Paint** mode).

Secondly, **Save** or **Pack as PNG** texture in **UV Image Editor** before closing Blender.

[image]

Images used in blender must exist as a file somewhere on the computer (or network). Saving the images will do that.

By default blender reads the images used from the place where they are saved. To make the .blend file self contained, with the images included within the project file, then pack the images

Answer (score 0):

First go to object mode and see right hand side up 3 small globe like structure there just click the third globe "if you are new to blender these definately works"[image]

Comment: [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org) Please don't post photos of your monitor, these are hard to read because we can't tell if we are looking at a reflection, a screen artifact or an actual issue with the model.