# Problem with texture applying

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I'm working on a model at the moment and I've spent hours texturing the torso of my character. The node setup is okay (I think), the paint worked perfectly, it was all fine and dandy until I stopped to texture a 2nd object. As soon as I had done this, the texture on the first object disappeared entirely, to be replaced with solid black. I suspect it might be something simple, but I honestly can't for the life of me figure it out & would really appreciate some help.

P.S I did UV unwrap, did create an image texture, and the image texture is still saved in the blend file. Did I need to save the UVs somehow perhaps?

[image]

Comment: Save your image to disk, often. I am quite sure there is sometimes 'little' problems like that in Blender... bad news for your painting

Comment: Image textures are not part of the blend file unless you pack them. If you painted a texture and did not save it as an image to the hard disk first, your image will be lost once you close blender and there is no way to recover it. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/why-did-the-texture-i-painted-in-texture-paint-mode-disappear

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your screenshot, I can see that it is a *generated image*. It is blank, which is why it is black. When adding a new image from the UV/image editor, choose an option other than blank, (*color grid or uv grid*) if you want to use a default image from within Blender.

[image]

You do need to save the image that you create as well if you use a generated image. You will notice an asterisk next to *image* in the editor header if the image has not been saved as it is in your screenshot.