# A way to fix the texture UV easly

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

[image]

Is there any way to fix the UV without moving the UV vertices ? (This mesh has got a lot of vertices and it would be a lot of time to make them correct) 
Maybe a tool like in the image editor softwares (clone tool) for UVs ?

Answer (score 2):

It's available under **Texture Paint**.

1. Go to *Texture Paint*.
2. Select *Clone Brush*.

[image: 1]

3. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> where you want to take sample from.
4. Adjust *Radius* and *Strength* then paint on the mesh.

[image: 2]

5. When you are done with painting don't forget to go to *Slot tab* and *Save all images*.

Comment: Thank you ! But I cannot find the "Save modified image" I have only "Save all images" but it will do nothing. Where could I find it ?

Comment: @Vettel.Sebastian Yeah, this is it "Save all images", I was writing from memory ;) I'll edit this.

Comment: But If I presss it and I go back to object mode the texture doesn't change. Only if I am in the texture paint mode.

Comment: @Vettel.Sebastian Do you have your image listed in "Available paint slots"?

Comment: I need to do with the "Material" or the "Image" Painting mode ?

Comment: If you are using image as texture select it on the list then save. I'll upload my blend file and you can check how it's done.

Comment: Or better, upload yours to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and I'll look what's wrong in your exact case. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/why-did-the-texture-i-painted-in-texture-paint-mode-disappear/7683#7683

Comment: It's now working with the Image paint mode, but I have a problem: It changes the whole texture so all of the meshes which are using the modified texture will be changed. Is there a way to change the UV like this instead of the texture ?

Comment: There is no way to hide seams trough editing UV's, as far as I know. It's theoretically possible but I don't think that with complex UV one could achieve it.

Comment: Make sure you don't use a tiling texture, but an unwrapped one with this approach.