# UV unwrapping texture problem, obvious seams and stretches

Tags: uv

I'm a Skyrim modder and have worked quite a long time with Blender and always struggled with UV unwrapping. A few days ago, I decided to model a tree and with all meshes it needs textures.

As you can see in this picture, you can see on the UV map that it has got stretches, which is already a problem. But making more seams to "restore" it, makes the seams look more obvious.

[image: Unwrapped with stretches and odd looking seams.[1]]

Every branch in the mesh is basically a cylinder. So, I made a seam at the bottom of each branch a seam and just took one line towards the tip and made a seam. This way it should be able to lay it flat. At the bottom of the tree I made a seam that goes upwards, but it makes the seam very obvious if you're closing in on the mesh. Is there any tips to avoid those obvious seams and the stretching?

Thanks for reading.

[image: The seams I made for the mesh.]

Comment: This could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72913/a-way-to-fix-the-texture-uv-easly/72915#72915

Comment: Something like https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79338/29586 might help - the Python code unwraps the mesh so that the UV faces are all oriented correctly (so the grain is along the branch) and the 'seam' along the branches matches up to the edge of your texture. Using a seamless texture will wrap the texture around each of the branches while the unwrapping ensures that the pattern also wraps seamlessly around each branching.