# I hit a key stroke and my texture turned Pastel purple. How to GetTexture Back?

Tags: rigging

I was working on the Rigging for Dragon and I hit an unknown key stroke and my Texture turned Hot Purple. Nothing I do fixes it. Tried reloading the Texture to not avail. I turn off The Textured Solid and my model returns to colorless form. I did something to the texture or What not sure. ANY have an Idea on how to get my texture back?

Comment: This means the image is not found. If you go to UV Image Editor and reopen the file (not reloading), is it still purple?

Comment: Yes it is still purpal

Comment: [Why did the texture I painted in texture paint mode disappear?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7681/2217)