# The Image textures on nodes and the UV texture of UV image editor are not showing

Tags: node-editor, uv-image-editor

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0r0UnaIK_Y&t=3s) of how to make a realistic eye.

Everything was fine; I saved the file and then went to sleep, the next day... BOOM, the textures were gone, and when I check on the nodes I can see they are there but not showing in the 3d view nor material preview, the same with the UV images editor, and even when I made the process over again (selecting all, unwrapping, editing, bla bla bla), they were still not showing.

[image]

Everything, every image texture has gone, I mean, what happened? I didn't touch it, I just let it the same as I finished.

Comment: Can you upload the .blend here? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and send the link?

Comment: Did you save your textures as images?

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/why-did-the-texture-i-painted-in-texture-paint-mode-disappear/7682#7682

Comment: Nope, maybe that's the problem. Let me try, i'll tell you ^^

Comment: TBH, i didn't know about that, the tutorial didn't mention that, so... that's it

Comment: I tried what is mentioned in that link, but still nothing, or atleast i don't see any change.

Comment: Here's my blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3851" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3851/)