# Model and materials turn black after I reopen the project

Tags: materials, texture-painting

When I reopen my saved project file, my model and materials turn black.
This happens all the time when I open the project. All the texture paintings were saved and displayed as painted.

Could you please help me?

P.S. I have the newest version of blender, so all the actions were done in one particular version.

[image: Materials are black and texture paintings are ok]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did the texture I painted in texture paint mode disappear?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/why-did-the-texture-i-painted-in-texture-paint-mode-disappear)

Answer (score 1):

Painted textures need to be saved as image files first.

Blender doesn't save them for you when you close then project or when you save the blend file.

Unless you save the textures manually you will not get them back next time the project is opened.

Comment: Thank you very much!
The problem is solved )