# UV map / model turned black on saving - how to recover?

Tags: texturing, uv

In the middle of touching up a new texture, I pressed save and suddenly my textures all turned black on the model and UV texture - just vanished.

I tried reopening the file in another instance of Blender, I tried to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> too and it just did this weird patchy thing on my texture.

How do I recover it and what did I do wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, their is no way to recover your texture. Their currently is a patch to allow for auto-saving images, but it may not go into a release of blender :(.

Answer (score 8):

This is a [known limitation](https://developer.blender.org/T40419), currently images are not saved with the rest of the .blend file. This means that reloading the .blend or even undoing in some modes will cause unsaved changes to textures to be lost (*Global undo* works by reloading an older version of the .blend).

To save your images, press <kbd>F3</kbd> to save it to your hard drive, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to save changes to an existing image on your hard drive. Or press *Image editor > Header > Image > Pack* to embed it in the .blend, and press *Pack* again to save changes to an embedded file:

[image]

You can tell when your image has unsaved changes because there is a asterisk after the image menu in the header:

[image]

---

As GiantCowFilms mentioned, there is [a patch](https://developer.blender.org/D398) which adds autosave functionality for images. [It has not currently been decided whether it should be included or not](https://developer.blender.org/D398#comment-1):

> Note, I'd like to have some better way to do this then simply adding another option, it seems a but weak and doesn't really fit into painting workflow.
>
> But doing this by default is a bit risky too.

Comment: Thanks for the patch info(external auto-save), I did not realized this was in yet.  Campbell wrote that he included this in master on the 22nd of June but I've been using a build made a week after that and I see no difference nor can I see anything in the UI or User Preferences to access this.  Do you know what's going on here?

Comment: @MarcClintDion It's not in master, but the code is written. You'll have to apply the patch yourself before you build.