# What can cause a texture to disappear on a mesh?

Tags: mesh, texturing

I am working on a scene with a Lighthouse in it.  I created and textured it after partitioning different sections so that it would be easier to place the textures and then rejoined the mesh.  Everything looked great yesterday but today the lighthouse has lost one texture.  I can partition the mesh again and replace the mesh and then rejoin it but I don't understand what happened.

Can someone explain what might have caused this and how I can avoid it in the future?

The text I'm using refers to Blender 2.5.  It says, "If you notice any strange effects when rendering, try entering Edit Mode, select all vertices and use the "Recalculate" Normals, or "Remove Doubles" options in the Tool Shelf.  As a result of separating the mesh the Normals may have flipped, or you may have created a double mesh."

In Blender 2.72 I cannot find a way to Recalculate Normals or Remove Doubles.

[image]

Comment: Could you add some more details?

Comment: Have you created the texture in Blender? If you have, make sure to save it or pack it into the .blend file.

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14050/uv-map-model-turned-black-on-saving-how-to-recover

Comment: @RandyVanNostrand select all the vertices and hit 'Ctrl'+'N' to recalculate the normals;  remove doubles is in the tools shelf on the left

Comment: This isn't a problem with the normals (those look like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3606/599)). Make sure the mapping for your texture is still set properly. If you are using UV coordinates, ensure a UV map exists.