# How to apply hand painted textures

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-painting

So I am trying to make a model with hand painted textures. I marked some seams and UV unwrapped it to start painting. (maybe i forgot a step?), but then i try to apply it. I don't really know how to apply it. And once I thought i succeeded, but when I opened up the file again it was blanc.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: saving the blend file doesn't save texture files, you have to do it manually. check http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14050/uv-map-model-turned-black-on-saving-how-to-recover