# How to make textures in Blender without any flat work with a painting program? (3D painting)

Tags: mesh, texturing, armature

I've made a complex model, what would be a nightmare to texture in gimp. So I'm asking you, if there is an option to paint in Blender itself, watching my 3D creation? It would be a lot easier and faster that way. If you need the model, just ask for it. Oh, and I've added armature to it. Will the texture follow the body while it is deformed?

Comment: texture paint mode, same menu as object/edit/weight paint modes in 3D view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a ***Texture Paint*** mode and paint the textures using a ***Stencil*** option.

Add a *new material* to your object. Join all the meshes using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Unwrap the model using *Smart UV Project*.
[image]

In *Uv Editor* add a new image texture and name it. Then save it (*Image-->Save as Image*).
[image]

In **CYCLES** Setup the nodes as pictured below. In the *Image Texture* node open up the newly created image.
[image]

In **BLENDER INTERNAL RENDER** add a new *Paint Slot*-->*Diffuse Color* in a *Tools* bookmark of a *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>).
[image]

Enter the ***Texture Paint*** mode and set up the *shading type* to ***Texture***. Add a new texture in the panel on the left, then go to the *Texture* header on the right, select ***Brush*** and open a texture, which will be used as a stencil for painting.
[image]

Enable a ***Stencil*** option in a panel on the left. Press:

-LMB to paint through the stencil

-RMB to move it

-<kbd>Shift</kbd>+RMB to make the stencil bigger and smaller

-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+RMB to rotate it.
[image]

You may also *uncheck* the *Occlude, Cull and Normal* boxes to paint on the invisible parts of the mesh.
[image]

Save your image when you're done with painting.
[image]

Comment: This has to be stressed: Painted textures do not get saved as part of the file automatically,  **you do have to save** as an image file first , otherwise your texture will be lost the moment you close the file.  Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14050/uv-map-model-turned-black-on-saving-how-to-recover

Comment: Thank you. I guess I can use this too, but I'm working with simple textures first.