# why are my textures missing when I reopen the model?

Tags: texturing

I have made a model, with quite a few textures (most of them is downloaded and edited with gimp, all exported as png), but sometimes when I open it, they are missing. I think I just misclicked somewhere. I wouldn't mind that, because to reopen them takes just a few seconds, but I want to share it with some other people and I couldn't do that if I wasn't sure that it would be complete.

Comment: Are you changing file location on your hard drive? Do you have them on an external drive?

Comment: Are the textures something you painted? They need to be asved as images first otherwise they will be lost see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/why-did-the-texture-i-painted-in-texture-paint-mode-disappear and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14050/uv-map-model-turned-black-on-saving-how-to-recover

Comment: I didn't move them, I didn't paint them. thy are made from photos