# Painted textures turning black

Tags: texturing

I keep having this problem where my painted textures keep turning completely black. I cant just reapply them, because the image itself is being corrupted, or something. Does anybody know how to fix this?

[image: The corrupt UV map]

Comment: What have you done before it turns black?

Comment: Did you save your image? Unsaved and unpacked images will reset themselves.

Comment: How do i save my image? And i'm not sure of what i did to trigger it...

Comment: Oh wait... i think it may just be time-based, happens after a certain amount of time, how do I save it so it wont reset?

Comment: Image reseting can't be time-based; the image might become black in case if you didn't save it to your hard drive (or elsewhere) prior to saving project and closing Blender. This happens because if image isn't saved Blender erases all the changes made and returns image settings to default ones.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14050/uv-map-model-turned-black-on-saving-how-to-recover

Comment: It happens while i'm still in blender, though.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is caused by not "Packing" the image.
In the image editor, go to the image you want to pack/save and **Image**-> **Pack as .png**.
Now when you close and reopen your project your texture wont be lost because it will have been packed into the .blend file.

Hope this helps

Comment: It's better in general to *save* image with F3 so it will actually exist outside of the .blend file (packing also works of course but it's more like a workaround for this exact problem).